# Why does importing tensorflow in ipython cause segmentation fault?

Tags: tensorflow, ipython

Tensorflow 2.9.1 and ipython 7.34.0 (python 3.7.5).  I can import tensorflow in plain python, but I get the segmentation fault from ipython.  This is in a python venv.  I also have a conda venv with all the same packages which works.  What might cause this?

Comment: Hi @Mastiff, Could you please provide the details of your OS and did you install tensorflow using pip? Thank You.